# Ruby, Convert cron range into digit

Tags: ruby

Using Ruby

I would like that any ranges that appear in a `cron` to be expanded to the contained numbers in the range ex:

```
0,5,7,30-35  1,3-8,20  * * *  /script.sh
```

expanded :

```
0,5,7,31,32,33,34,35  1,3,4,5,6,7,8,20  * * * /script.sh
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What is `*** /script.sh`?

Comment: What kind of object is that? Especially, what is going on with around `... 35 1 ...`? What is the logic that gives (presumably) `0,5,7,31,32,33,34,35` for `0,5,7,30-35`?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `0,5,7,30-35 1,3-8,20 * * * /script.sh` is a string, a simple `gsub` would work:

```
str = "0,5,7,30-35 1,3-8,20 * * * /script.sh"

str.gsub(/(\d+)-(\d+)/) { ($1..$2).to_a.join(',') }
#=> "0,5,7,30,31,32,33,34,35 1,3,4,5,6,7,8,20 * * * /script.sh"
```

Comment: That is different from what OP gave as "expanded." Hint: `30`.

Comment: Nice, I was about to post the exact same solution. @sawa I think it was a typo of the OP to exclude the `30` of the range `30-35`.

Comment: Good one, Stefan. A variant: `str = "1-3,5,6-8,10,12-14"; 
str.gsub(/\d+-\d+/) { |r| f,l=r.split('-'); [*(f..l)].join(',')  }
=> "1,2,3,5,6,7,8,10,12,13,14"`. Can you explain this (for `str` above): `str.gsub(/(\d+)-(\d+)/, $1+'-'+$2) => "12-14,5,12-14,10,12-14"`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland `$1` and `$2` are global variables, referring to the 1st and 2nd capture group of the last match. Without a block that's `12` and `14`. You can use `gsub`'s `\\d` notation instead: `str.gsub(/(\d+)-(\d+)/, "\\1-\\2")`